# Entity Framework querying with max

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Someone asks me to convert the T-SQL statement into LINQ to EF query:

```
SELECT * FROM  CopperPrices  
where ID in 
  (select max(ID) as ID from copperprices group by market, pname)
```

I use common LINQ-TO-OBJECT ideas and give the following answer:

```
class CopperPrice
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
}

var result = from p in copperPrices
      group p by new { Market = p.Market, PName = p.PName } into g
      select g.OrderByDescending(p => p.ID).First();
```

But it's not working in EF because of the following exception:

> The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation.
>   Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead

Can the above T-SQL statement be converted to one LINQ query statement?

Comment: What happens when you do as the error message suggests? `FirstOrDefault` should give the same results as `First` if you know you've got a nonempty set, so if `FirstOrDefault` is accepted by EF, and `First` isn't, use `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var result1 = copperPrices.GroupBy(g => new { g.Market, g.PName }).Select
     (
         x => x.ToList().OrderByDescending(z => z.ID).FirstOrDefault()
     );
```

The important part here is the .Select(x => x.ToList()). The ToList returns the values of an IGrouping, each of which is what you ultimately want to order and select the max of.

Comment: My linq statement can obviously return a few items.

Comment: Your two queries, if they can run at all, both return a single value.

Comment: @hvd they do run and return identical results. True they return a single value, but that value is a "Grouping" which can be enumerated over. Inside the grouping are all "CopperPrices" which have the maximum ID.

Comment: @hvd you're right. I confused myself...but I believe I've got the correct solution now! :) I updated the answer above

Comment: All the edits look more like a guessing game than an answer, to be honest. And I doubt that LINQ to Entities will accept `ToList()` inside of the projection. Did you test it?

Comment: My comment on your previous version of your answer was wrong, BTW, I've deleted it.